# How to implement a hash table with 2 keys?

Tags: c++, key, hashtable

I have a following problem: a single value, which can be associated with two different keys. Example:

- uint64 key1 -> Value
- uint32 key2 -> Value

So a query can be twofold:

table.find(uint64 key1) or
table.find(uint32 key2)

key1 and key2 are completely independent.
Is there a possibility to implement ONE table having access through two keys WITHOUT duplicating the items?

One possible solution (psedocode):

```
class TwoKeyHashTable {
  Value find(uint64);
  Value find(uint32);

  insert(key1, key2, value) {
    insert_into_table(key1, value);
    insert_into_table(key2, value);
  }

  struct Item {
    uint64 key1;
    uint32 key2;
    Value value;
  } *table;
};
```

However this solutions doubles the number of items in the table. I have hundreds of millions of items and I want to keep the entire table in the memory, so I am asking if something more memory efficient exists?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're talking about implementing this data structure but not stating which language or languages you're willing to use.
Also take into account that hundreds of millions of items might not all fit in memory at once.

Comment: C++. I already implemented over 10 specialized hash tables, so I won't have problems with the low level implementation. Just the idea or algorithm will be enough... :-)

Comment: Please show the code you have. You're unlikely to get an answer this way.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... I quite clearly specified the question and the requirements with the class above. The hash tables I implemented are completely unrelated to my problem. I only wanted to emphasize, that I have quite a bit experience with implementations and what I am seeking here are algorithms and ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, I am surprised that there are no ideas around... :-/ 
So I implemented the table, with duplicating of all items, as follows:

```
class TwoKeysHashTable {
 public:
  struct Item {
    uint64 key1;
    uint32 key2;
    int32 value;

    Item() : key1(0), key2(0) { }

    Item(uint64 k1, uint32 k2, int val)
       : key1(k1), key2(k2), value(val) { }
  };

  ...

  Item *Find(uint64 key) const;
  Item *Find(uint32 key) const;
  int Insert(uint64 key1, uint32 key2, int value);

 private:
  Item *FindKey1(uint64 key, int *return_index) const;
  Item *FindKey2(uint32 key, int *return_index) const;

  int GetNextIndex(int start_index, int counter) const;
  void Rehash();

  Item *array_;
  int number_key1_;
  int number_key2_;
  int allocated_items_;
};
```

In order not to duplicate the (real) data, it is stored in a compressed array, and 'Item::value' is the index to that array. 'Insert' calls both 'FindKey1' and 'FindKey2' to query if keys are already in the table and if not, new Items will be inserted at the returned indexes. 
I used open hashing to keep the array is compact as possible. Despite all the effort, the table is still using over 8GB of memory for my data (and I am not counting the actual data, the 'value' is pointing to).

Any ideas how to do it even more memory efficiently? Thanks...

Comment: Did you ever figure out a more efficient way to do this? Not looking for code, just some ideas.